# Can't see component in backend menu but can access it via a URL

Tags: component, administration, fabrik

I have a component called Fabrik installed on my site (running version 3.4.1) which works perfectly.

Some months ago we migrated some content and other components across to the site from an older version of Joomla (2.x).

Since that migration I can no longer see the Fabrik component in the Components menu. It is still installed and works exactly as expected. It is visible in the global config menu and I can also access it via a URL. I can access other components through this menu, but not this particular one for some reason.

But I would really like to see it in that menu again.

What can I do to see this component in the Components menu again please?

Comment: Have you try to apply an update yo fabrik?. It seems that the link is missing and maybe an upgrade can reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks @PieroMarsilio, I regularly update the component so no, that hasn't helped resolve it.

Comment: Have you used a custom mod_menu? eg:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/admin-menu-manager

Answer (score 1):

Most likely something wrong in the #__menu table. 
If you have access to phpmyadmin, I would start by having a look there. 
Compare the values of other administrator components menu entries that you can see with the values of the Fabrik entry.

It is also possible that the Fabrik entry is missing completely. If so check in the database of the other website where it is working for the working configuration and try and copy the settings from there.